# Database Normalization into 3rd Normal Form (3NF)

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization

I am trying to normalize the following ERD [placed here](http://i42.tinypic.com/fng2a9.jpg) into 3NF.

I have completed 1NF but, I am stuck on normalizing it any further. Are the structures specified below in 3NF?

```
Port (PortID,Name,Country,Population,PassPort_Req,DockingFee)

Port_Attractions (AttractionID, PortID, AttractionDescription)

Passenger (PassNum,Name, Nationality,Age)

Passenger_Address (PassNum,Street,City,State,Zip)

Ship (ShipNum, Name,Weight, YrBuilt, Capacity)

Sailor(SailorID, FName, LName, YearsService, Nationality)

Cruise (SerialNumber, SailingMonth, SailingDay, SailingYear, ReturnMonth, ReturnDay, ReturnYear, DeparturePort)
```

Comment: A bit of consistency might have helped you. What about a sailor who is a passenger? PS don't break dates up like that, you end up having to deal with 50/45/2013.

Comment: The assumption is that a "sailor" will not be considered a passanger

Comment: Not really what I was saying. If a sailor took passage. Then you could make an argument for a person table and liked to sailors and passengers. Basically not enough in your design for 'obvious 2NF and 3NF improvements.

Comment: what are the applicable FDs ?  Without this info, the question/exercise is not answerable.